# How can I send an object (byteArray) to an AJAX PageMethod via Javascript?

Tags: c#, asp.net, javascript, ajax

I need to send a byte array from javascript into a c# page method.  The int and string variables work fine, but when I step through the c# code, the "object" which was the byte array is null, even though I checked to see if it had a value in JS.

```
     var byteArrayObj = GetBinaryDataFromFile(filePath);

     var tranAttachmentName = filePath.replace(/^.*\\/, '');
     PageMethods.AddFileToTran(tranId, tranAttachmentName, byteArrayObj, RefreshPage, onTimeout, onError);


     function GetBinaryDataFromFile(strFileName)
     {
         var streamObj = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Stream");
         streamObj.Type = 1;
         streamObj.Open();
         streamObj.LoadFromFile(strFileName);
         var ByteArray = streamObj.Read();
         streamObj.Close();


         return(ByteArray);
     }
```

**c# code :**

```
    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public bool AddFileToTran(int tranId, string tranAttachmentName, object byteArrayObj)
    {
        DBConnector dbConnectorObj = new DBConnector("cnnDataTracking");
        try
        { ........
```

The object byteArrayObj comes in null.

Comment: As a debugging aid, I suggest that you also use a protocol peeker to ensure that the args are right as they come into your server. You can use Fiddler if the client is a PC.

Comment: Is your byte array in js an actual array type?  Have you tried making the byteArrayObj in your page method a byte[] instead of a System.Object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out using the postback was the way to go on this.  It didn't need to be asynchronous anyway.  Thanks for the comments.